# Missing Linker properties for Xamarin Android in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: xamarin.android, linker, .net-6.0, visual-studio-2022

There was a good option to control Linking of libraries in Visual Studio 2019.
Since we are using .NET 6 now and for that we have to use Visual Studio 2022.

I cannot see Linker Properties in Visual Studio 2022.
Can someone please guide where it is in VS 2022, probably I am missing something.

Comment: You can check this article about [Linking on Android](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/deploy-test/linker) for more infromation.

Answer (score 0):

You can find it by right clicking your projects android version's name from solution menu and then selecting properties. Then you need to select Android Options from the left menu, and scroll down to the end of the page. Linking is controlled from Linking properties > Linking > SDK and User Assemblies (for example)